# How to find the the force necessary to pull from a cylinder so it keeps in place?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> A cylinder of $\textrm{500 grams}$ in mass has a very thin flexible
>   non elastic tin wire of negligible weight winded around it as shown in
>   the figure from below. By how much a force must be applied to pull the
>   wire so that the cylinder spins and keeps in place?. Assume that the
>   coefficient of friction is $0.3$ and the acceleration due gravity is
>   $9.8\,\frac{m}{s^2}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{3 N}\\
2.&\textrm{2.5N}\\
3.&\textrm{1.5N}\\
4.&\textrm{0.15N}\\
5.&\textrm{4.5N }\\
\end{array}$

I'm not sure exactly if I'm understanding this problem correctly. What I've attempted to do here was to assume that the condition which must be met is given by:

$\sum ^n_{i=1}\tau_{i}=0$

Therefore:

$-F\cos 37^{\circ}\cdot R-F\sin 37^{\circ}\cdot R + f_R\cdot R = 0$

Hence:

$f_R=F\cos 37^{\circ}+F\sin 37^{\circ}=F\frac{4}{5}+F\frac{3}{5}$

$f_R=\frac{7}{5}F$

But:

$f_R=\mu N$

$N=mg-F\sin 37^{\circ}$

$f_R=\frac{3}{10}(mg-F\sin 37^{\circ})=\frac{3}{10}\left(0.5\times 9.8-\frac{3F}{5}\right)$

Solving this thing yield:

$\frac{3}{10}\left(0.5\times 9.8-\frac{3F}{5}\right)=\frac{7}{5}F$

Hence:

$F=0.93\,N$

But it doesn't check with any of the alternatives given. What did I missunderstood?. Can someone help me here please?.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for the Physics Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The module of the torque is $F·R·\sin\alpha$ being $\alpha$ the angle between the force and the arm and this is not what you wrote that it rather seems the decomposition of some force. So, the condition of rotation equilibrium is:

$$f_R·R-F·R=0$$

But this doesn't matter because one of your implicit assumptions is wrong. You assumed that it is a problem of statics, but it isn't. If the (center of mass of the) cylinder has to be in place, it has to have an angular acceleration around its center of mass: the above equations doesn't hold.

By Hypothesis, the center of mass is not moving, thus, the total force along an horizontal axis is zero:

$$F\cos 37º-f_R=0$$

Then

$$f_R=\frac{4F}{5}$$

that, with the equation you got,

$$f_R=\frac{3}{10}\left(0.5\times 9.8-\frac{3F}{5}\right)$$

Gives $F=1.5$, approx.

We can get the angular acceleration from here:

$$I\alpha=F·R-f_R·R$$

Being $\alpha$ the angular acceleration and $I$ the moment of inertia of the cylinder around its symmetry axis.

Comment: How did you assume that there is no net horizontal force acting on it and yet that it has non-zero torque? The only forces acting on the cylinder with non-zero arms are those on the horizontal axis and they add up to zero.

Comment: @Km356 Of course it's possible zero net force and non zero torque! How if not can you spin a wheel in place?

Comment: Maybe I am confused. To spin a wheel in place, it must be attached to something that prevents the movement of its center of mass so that some force(which doesn't produce torque) opposes the horizontal force applied to the wheel. So this force stops the horizontal movement but doesn't affect the torque. This doesn't happen in this case since the opposing force itself (which is friction) produces a torque in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Km356 You can have two forces producing torque and preventing to move the center of mass. [Here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par_de_fuerzas#/media/Archivo:Par_de_fuerzas.jpg) we have a nice example of this.

Comment: OK I understand, but this is still not the case here, the applied force AND the friction force produce torques in the opposite directions. They do stop the center of mass but they act at the same point on the cylinder in opposite directions and this forces them to stop it from spinning too.

Comment: @Km356 the equations are clear. You have to consider all the forces acting over the cylinder, including the normal reaction of the floor.. Further, the applied force and friction don't act at the same point.

Comment: Sorry, I had to be more precise. The horizontal component of the force and the friction force act in opposite directions and they are the ones producing torque. The normal force and the vertical component of the applied force don't produce torque.

Comment: @Km356 Yes, they do. Check the formulas

Comment: Explain then. Don't the horizontal component and the force of friction produce torques in opposite directions? How do the normal force and the vertical component of $f$ produce torque? How do they make it rotate?

Comment: @Km356 I meant that they act. The equations are clear, the vertical component of F and the normal balance the weight, the horizontal component of the force balamces the friction, but the torque of F doesn't balance the torque of the friction.

Comment: This is the wonder of maths explaining nature that Galileo and all phycisists after him experiment: maths expand our perception of phenomena: even in this little problem we see what seemed different.

Comment: And why doesn't the torque from the horizontal component of the force balance the one from friction? They both act at the same point and in opposite directions and the equations guarantee that they have equal magnitudes!

Comment: It's not necessay to calculate torque by components. Choose the center, and see the arm of the force and the angle between arm and force, R and $\alpha$  in this case and set the module to $F·R\sin\alpha$, that being orthogonal arm and force is F·R.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't add up. Something is seriously wrong here. Thanks for your time.